# Image output when 2 conv 2d layers are applied

Tags: conv-neural-network, convolution

Can you please help me on below question. I have written below code for `MNIST` data set.
And in summary the first output is OK for me. But i am not sure why `(None, 30, 24, 32)` is displayed in second layer.

when `32(3*3)` filter applied on `32*26*26`, output should be `32*24*24`.

Thanks in advance...

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(1,28,28), data_format='channels_first'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3))
model.summary()
```

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_102 (Conv2D)          (None, 32, 26, 26)        320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_103 (Conv2D)          (None, 30, 24, 32)        7520
```

Answer (score 0):

In Line 3 - `model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3))`, the 2nd parameter `kernel_size` has been assigned `3` and the 3rd parameter `stride` has been assigned `3` instead of the `kernel_size` being assigned `(3,3)` or `3` and `stride` being assigned `1`.

For reference, `Convolution2D` definition from [Keras docs](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/) is:

```
`keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, kernel_size, strides=(1, 1), padding='valid', ...)`
```

So, Line 3 must be modified to: `model.add(Convolution2D(32,(3,3)))` or `model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,1))` or just `model.add(Convolution2D(32,3))` to achieve the desired convolution.

Note: Also `data_format` must be set to `channels_first` in order to get output to have shape: `(None,32,24,24)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply ....i have tried with  `model.add(Convolution2D(32,(3,3)))` , `model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,1))  ` and  `model.add(Convolution2D(32,3))`     but i dont get output as  32*24*24 ...also can you please let me know how to write code for  channels_first must be set to True.

Comment: Try this: `model.add(Convolution2D(32,(3,3),channels_first=True))`. You need to include `channels_first=True` to get (None,32,24,24), else you might get (None,24,24,32)

Comment: Thanks for the reply...i have tried  `model.add(Convolution2D(32,(3,3),channels_first=True))`  but it throws error  "('Keyword argument not understood:', 'channels_first')"

Comment: Oops! I meant `data_format='channels_first'` and I've edited the answer. Please try this: `model.add(Convolution2D(32,(3,3),data_format='channels_first'))`

Comment: Yes....its works fine..thanks for your time and effort. Wish u happy new year 2020

Comment: Wishing you the same! :)